# symfony forms file upload Validation not working for Ms Word Document

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony 1.4 and Propel as ORM. I have created a form using the Symfony Form, which contains some text inputs and file upload elements.
The form structure,

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
            'name'            =>new sfWidgetFormInput(),
            'mobile'          =>new sfWidgetFormInput(),
            'resume'          =>new sfWidgetFormInputFile()
    ));
$mime_array=array("application/pdf","application/msword");
$this->setValidators(array(
             'name'            =>new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
             'mobile'          =>new sfValidatorAnd(array(new sfValidatorNumber(),new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true, 'min_length' => 10, 'max_length' => 10)))), 
             'resume'          =>new sfValidatorFile(array('mime_types' => $mime_array))
    ));
```

But the file upload Validation not working for Ms Word files, but works for PDF files(as user can upload PDF or Ms Word Document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure but I think new office 2007 word docs require a different mime type:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

(add that to your array to test)

I believe the other one is for older word versions.

Here's some related reading: http://www.vladville.com/2007/04/office-2007-mime-types-for-apache.html

Comment: it is not working giving the error "Invalid mime type (text/plain)" when i uploaded a MsDoc file!

Comment: This might help: http://blog.o-x-t.com/2009/07/27/symfony-sfvalidatorfile-invalid-mime-type-textplain-for-png-images/

Comment: thank you @Tom it worked! what i did was, upgraded to PHP 5.3.4 and it started working.